# @SuppressWarnings more than one rule not working

Tags: pmd, sonarqube

PMD and SonarQube a nice tools but I have problems trying to suppress PMD warnings.

We use Lombok a lot in our project, so many of the model classes have a:
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
as an class-level annotations.

This works fine.

The problem is, that if I wan't to ignore one more rule, I would expect the following syntax:
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "PMD.UnusedPrivateField", "PMD.SingularField" })
This looks like the correct syntax, also reading the implementation of the PMD annotation.

However, this seems not to works:
None of the rules are now suppressed.

Comment: Are you using `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`? Maybe you accidentally imported the annotation from a different package.

Comment: I use the correct one.
I also use the one for findbugs, then its like:
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(value = { "EI_EXPOSE_REP2" }, justification = "Verified")

Comment: The FindBugs annotation will not work for PMD. Can you post a simplified example file to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would have expected this format (without the "value ="):

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.UnusedPrivateField", "PMD.SingularField"})
```

Similar format is working for me in PMD 5.1.3 (although Eclipse complains about them not being supported).

Comment: This is exactly the case, thanks :-)
I worked this out myself, but forgot to update my question.

Comment: In my case I was using a constant to save the description then it will not works because PMD analyse the source file I can't interpret the a constant reference for example

Answer (score 4):

As @colbadhombre writes:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.UnusedPrivateField", "PMD.SingularField"})
```

does the trick.

Regarding Eclipse:
Open Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings

- "Unhandled token in '@SuppressWarnings':" can be set to Ignore
- Likewise the "Unused '@SuppressWarnings' token" if the warnings are enabled